# python how to read a line until EOF

Tags: python, input

I am trying to read some lines until EOF for this question:

https://open.kattis.com/problems/tight

Here's what I've tried:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import sys


def get_ans(n, k):
    dp = defaultdict(int)
    total = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(n):
        for num in range(k+1):
            if num+1 <= k:
                dp[(i, num)] += dp[(i-1, num+1)]
            if num-1 >= 0:
                dp[(i, num)] += dp[(i-1, num-1)]
            dp[(i, num)] += dp[(i-1, num)]

            dp[(i, num)] = max(dp[(i, num)], 1)
            total[i] += dp[(i, num)]
    return total[n-1]/((k+1)**n)*100


def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if line == "":
            break
        print(line)
        k, n = map(int, input().split())
        ans = get_ans(n, k)

        print(str.format('{0:.6f}', ans))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Problem: if I copy the input and paste it all in the terminal to the running script, my output looks like this:**

My input:

```
4 1
2 5
3 5
8 7
```

Terminal Output

```
40.740741
3 5
```

It seems like the some lines aren't processed -- I don't understand why.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So you're looping over `sys.stdin` (and thus reading from it) and in the loop using `input()`, which reads data from `sys.stdin` as well. Looks your code ends up reading too much from `sys.stdin`. You should stick to one method of reading data from `sys.stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` I would suggest using a while loop and as already pointed out `input` as `input` handles incoming data from `sys.stdin` for you.

```
def main():
    line = input()
    while line:
        k, n = map(int, line.split())
        ans = get_ans(n, k)
        print(str.format('{0:.6f}', ans))

        line = input()
```

Answer (score -1):

As @ForceBru pointed out, I was splitting on `input()` instead of `line`.

Comment: This is a comment, not a proper answer